# Using an index for a ranged where

Tags: mysql

im storing down ranks in one of my app, and i frequently do this:

```
select count(*) from table where score > ?
```

and ? = the current person's score.  i intend to memcache this, and i use an index on this table, is there a good way to index it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the index on *score*

Have a look at [CREATE INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

It is recomended though to profile a couple of options, and also take into account that this filed might be regularly updated.

Comment: DESC postfix changed nothing ;-) even if it would work in mysql (this is false).


from your link: "An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are allowed for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order. "

Comment: OK, i see, that is pretty dull, will remove the desc, but stick with the index on score.

Comment: read something about search within B-TREE. order changed nothing there (for 1 column indexes)

Answer (score 1):

yep, index with "score" as left-most part will be used with this query